# Selenium - How to match image presence and location on page

Tags: testing, selenium

My query is that - I have my images on webpage- a logo or say navigation bar i can store as an image. Can i test using selenium presence of these images on a webpage when loaded along with the position of the image on page.
What my issue is that i need to actually look at image objects in HTML and also may be images not in HTML but they are partial screenshots of webpage which i want to match. This test will help me pick alignment issues - in case my navigation bar is now going to second row i can match with previous stored image to check.

Thanks
VB

Answer (score 1):

An example on how to check if a particular image is present:

In this page:http://www.google.ie/firefox?client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official

**Selenese command**

```
Command: verifyElementPresent
Target: //td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/img[@src='/images/firefox/Fx4Launch.png']
```

Hint: If you want help to get the XPath for a particular element I recommend you using a plugin like Firebug (http://getfirebug.com/)

Put an extra "\" in the beginning of the xpath copied by Firebug, otherwise selenium do not find the element.

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that an image is at a location like so:

```
verifyElementPresent //div/p/img
```

This example uses [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xpath) to locate an `<img>` element that follows a `<div>` and `<p>` tag.

But verifying that a screenshot is the same as the rendered page? You're talking about a completely different problem, which is image recognition. Selenium is a tool for automated acceptance testing.