# Selenium: How to locate all the images on a webpage without knowing their id or name attribute?

Tags: selenium, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

Let us say, I loaded a URI with selenium. I have no idea how the elements are named in that page (I do not know the id, name ... of elements). I want to download all the possible pictures that may exist on that webpage. This problem is solved through the first answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python). But how can I located with selenium all the pictures that exist on that webpage ?
I checked answers for similar questions like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587616/selenium-how-to-match-image-presence-and-location-on-page) but the answers are not useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to find by tag name as all images will have an image tag you can just get every element on that page with that tag. In python i believe it will be using (note note find_element_by_tag_name as that would return just one of the elements)

find_elements_by_tag_name

and you will want to find elements with the img tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_img.asp

Comment: Yes, but I do not have the names and ids of those pictures (it is an automated process, I can not do it by hand)

Comment: You do not need the id or names tag is part of the html structure of a page and will be what all images on the page are embedded in so by searching via tag you will final all the elements with that tag which will be all the pictures

Comment: Ok, I will run a small script and test your solution. Regards.

Comment: you dont need to know any id, name, just find_element_by_tag_name('img') and you will have all images in page

Comment: The problem with this solution is that using find_elements_by_tag_name with img is that it will not find background images set in the css..

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can do something like this

> driver.find_element_by_tag_name('img')

Hope that's help.